# GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.1

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, gnu

Here's the sequence of the commands I tried.

1. screen on pressing the power button:

[image: 1]

2. screen after *Enter* on Ubuntu

[image: 2]

3. after *ctrl+D* and trying `fsck -f /dev/sda`

[image: 3]

4. tried `mount -a` then
   `apt install root-system-bin` then `apt-get update`

[image: 4]

5. `/dev/sda1` to `/dev/sda8`

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

[image: 7]

Comment: What OS/release are you using?   That package doesn't actually match any supported release of Ubuntu (*though it could be a typo given it looks typed, or your system is badly in need of upgraded packages*)  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=grub

Comment: Last week I had the similar trouble.
 
File system was corrupted. 
Had fsck -f /dev/sda run for sda1 to sda8 and fixed the corrupted files. 
System was then in good condition. 
It's been four days after that and the there is this screen [1] again.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Problem solved for now. System is accessible.

Solution: Tried `fsck -f /dev/sda` for `/dev/sda1` to `/dev/sda8` for multiple iterations.

Looks like, the same problem is repeating. I'll have to shift system OS from *Ubuntu* to *Windows*